# multiple except with one try

Tags: python, django

I want to use two different exception:

```
class toto:
   def save():
     try:#gestion du cours
        cours = Cours.objects.get(titre=self.titre, date=old_date)
        cours.date = self.date
        cours.save()
     except Cours.DoesNotExist:
        Cours.objects.create(titre=self.titre, date=self.date, valeur=self.cours)
     except IntegrityError:
        pass
```

but it don't work.
why ?

edit: fixed intentation

Comment: Could you explain what doesn't work about it? Are you trying to handle both exceptions in the same case? Or are you saying that having these multiple exception statements is not working?

Comment: As written, this isn't valid code. Did you cut and paste from your actual code? Are you getting syntax errors from the first two lines, or do you have some other problem?

Comment: Maybe you want to save the newly created Cours object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expands on @arie's comment.

```
  def save():
     obj,created = Cours.objects.get_or_create(titre=self.titre, date=old_date)
     if created:
         obj.date = self.date
         obj.save()
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

> A convenience method for looking up an object with the given kwargs,
>   creating one if necessary.
>
> Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the retrieved or
>   created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new
>   object was created.

If you want to catch an `IntegrityError`, simply wrap it in a try:

```
try:
  obj,created = Cours.objects.get_or_create(titre=self.titre, date=old_date)
     if created:
        obj.date = self.date
        obj.save()
except IntegrityError:
   # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what could be happening, the `IntegrityError` is being raised in the exception part.

Try if this solves your problem:

```
def save():
    try: #gestion du cours
        cours = Cours.objects.get(titre=self.titre, date=old_date)
        cours.date = self.date
        cours.save()
    except Cours.DoesNotExist:
        try:
            Cours.objects.create(titre=self.titre, date=self.date, valeur=self.cours)
        except IntegrityError:
            pass
```

Comment: Thats an interesting take on what he might be trying to do. I didn't think that he was actually trying to catch an exception on the create() method

Comment: Also note that there is a shortcut for these kind of situations: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Answer (score 0):

The logic in exception is that if an exception is thrown in the `try` block, then attempts to capture are made in cascade. in your case, it's like this:

```
if try... throws an exception then:
   if exception is Cours.DoesNotExist then:
      Cours.objects.create(...)
   else if exception is IntegrityError then:
      pass
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have missing `:` after after `def toto` and `def save()`. The indentation is also wrong.

It seems better to first just test `Cours.DoesNotExist` and if needed create within the try block. I'm not sure how your Cours works, but something more like this:

```
class toto:
  def save():
    try:#gestion du cours
       try:
         cours = Cours.objects.get(titre=self.titre, date=old_date)
       except Cours.DoesNotExist as e:
         print("trying to create " self.titre)
         Cours.objects.create(titre=self.titre, date=self.date, valeur=self.cours)
         # I guess you need this again now: 
         cours = Cours.objects.get(titre=self.titre, date=old_date)   
       cours.save()
       cours.date = self.date
    except Cours.DoesNotExist as e:
       print("not even at second try: ",e)
       raise
    except IntegrityError:
       pass
    except BaseException as e:
       print(" re-raise of some exception: ",type(e),e)
       raise
```

Note that the order in which you catch exceptions matters if one tested exception is derived from another one.